# Shrink image on click in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

In my frame I have a list with three images. Each subsequent image should appear on the next click, below the previous image. This is working fine, but I would like the previous image(s) to shrink in size when the next image appears. Is there a quick way to decrease the image size when the new overlay appears?

This is the code I use now (edited):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
     \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics<1->[width=1\textwidth]{./image/pic1.jpg}

      \includegraphics<2->[width=1\textwidth]{./image/pic2.jpg}

      \includegraphics<3->[width=1\textwidth]{./image/pic3.jpg}
     \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
     \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}

      \includegraphics<2>[width=1\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<2>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}

      \includegraphics<3>[width=1\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[width=1\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-c}
     \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** As Gonzalo suggested, if you want to shrink previous figures and not only vertically reduce them, it's better to use `scale` includegraphics' option

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
     \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}

      \includegraphics<2>[scale=.1]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<2>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}

      \includegraphics<3>[scale=.1]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[scale=.1]{example-image-b}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-c}
     \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Just a suggestion: for the "minimized" images it would be better to control the scale and not the width/height, so they won't be distorted:       `\includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<2>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics<3>[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}\par
      \includegraphics<3>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-c}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You're right I misunderstood `shrink`.